# Filled contour plot with arbitrary integer labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a 2D grid of points *z*. Each point has an associated label. The labels are from the range [0.0, 4.0].

I want to do a contourf plot having a single contour line for each label occurring in *z*.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

cmap = colors.ListedColormap([
    'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'royalblue'
])

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, num=50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, x)

z1 = np.ones(shape=xx.shape)
z1 = np.tril(z1)
levels1 = np.arange(z1.min(), z1.max() + 2) - 0.5

z2 = np.ones(shape=xx.shape) + 3
z2 = np.tril(z2)
levels2 = np.arange(z2.min(), z2.max() + 2) - 0.5

print('Labels (left): ', np.unique(z1))
print('Labels (right): ', np.unique(z2))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

im1 = axes[0].contourf(xx, yy, z1, levels=levels1, cmap=cmap)
im2 = axes[1].contourf(xx, yy, z2, levels=levels2, cmap=cmap)
# c = axes.contour(xx, yy, z, colors='k', levels=levels, linwidths=.1)

fig.colorbar(im1, ax=axes[0], ticks=np.arange(0, 5))
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=axes[1], ticks=np.arange(0, 5))

plt.show()
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

For the plot on the left everything is as expected. However, for the plot on the right its not. Here, the grid contains the two labels 0 and 4. So, there should be only two colors, blue and red. However, contourf also draws contour lines for all the labels in between, i.e 1, 2, and 3.

How can I fix this? Ideally, the plot on the right should look exactly as the plot on the left (except for the colors).

[image]

Comment: This is because your `levels2` contains more numbers than your `levels1`. You may want to review how you compute that array.

Comment: how should I define levels2 if my labels are 1.0 and 4.0 ? [-0.5, 0.5, -3.5, 4.5] will draw a contour line for 2.0 as well.

Comment: I guess the question is a bit, are those levels 1,2,3 present somewhere or not? If not, you can still work with 2 distinct levels 1 and 4 and specify the `levels` as `[-2,2,6]`.

Comment: There are different cases, sometimes all levels are present, sometimes only a subset. So what I actually need is a way to specify levels which works for all combinations of levels.

Comment: I kind of guessed that judging from your previous question, but I guess it would be good to have this requirement in the question itself, as other readers may not find it obvious. Also, I guess you don't want to plot triangles all the time, correct? As this would be easy. Concerning the question itself, I currently have no good idea, but what seems clear is that using a `contour` plot is not the way to go. Contour plots (as their name suggests) would always draw all contours - and those are calculated via interpolation. So there is no way to get rid of intermediate contours.

Comment: Yes this is correct. So what could be an alternative to `contour` here?

Comment: Well, if I knew, I'd have provided an answer already. :-) The only alternative I could think of was `tripcolor` but that shows some similar behaviour.

Comment: `pcolormesh` [could be a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFopo.png), not sure if this suits you. Also, `contourf` with a thick black `contour` on top [might get you around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh82b.png) the issue.

Comment: Ok I will try those. Thanks for your help!